# Friendly URl on Facebook Share

Tags: facebook, web-applications, web, facebook-sharer

I am working on Facebook Share for my website and basically it is working fine but just a little wrinkle there. Whenever user does a share on Facebook, it share the URL on his/her wall. But I would like to add some description into it like all the News papers do it.CNN and NYTimes. When a user shares something, URL will go on the wall but there would be title of the article or something that is in a bigger fonts and is able to draw people's attention.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Facebook API to create Dialogs and post to User Feed,

**a direct URL example:**

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=APP_ID&
  link=https://YOUR_DOMAIN&
  picture=http://YOUR_DOMAIN/image.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=API%20Dialogs&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=http://YOUR_DOMAIN/response
```

**a Javascript example:**

```
function postToFeed() {
    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
        picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
        name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
        caption: 'Reference Documentation',
        description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
        alert("Post ID: " + response['post_id']);
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/